# How to check impact of schema change on all reports on SSRS Server?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have more than 500 reports on the SSRS server. Now for any change in Schema of the database, I want to ensure that all of the reports using the object that has got changed in recent schema changes are working well.
Is there a way to list down all the SSRS reports using a particular object? Or,
Is there a way to list down all the SSRS reports which have invalid dataset?

Comment: assuming you have the reportsproject locally, you can extract the query and execute it in a test and check for errors

Comment: @Bacon the reportproject is not local, whatever reports we have is on SSRS server only.

Comment: then im afraid, you have to use the ssrs webservice api to traverste throu all installed reports and execute everyone and check if it returns a report or an error

Comment: Can you even access the underlying SQL in the report with the APIs? Certainly you can't with Powershell (using the `ReportingServicesTools` module); the actual SQL query is encrypted in the database.

Comment: @Larnu which API you are talking about to access the underlying SQL?